# Is cutting corners in the Temple allowed?

Tags: halacha, hashkafah-philosophy, beis-hamikdash, architecture-design

Last week I went on an archeology studies field trip from my university. We toured parts of the City of David and around and under the Kotel. It turns out that the bottom-most blocks that form the base of the Kotel and the other outer walls of the Herodian-expanded Temple Mount were not perfectly hewn like the above-ground ones are. Here are two examples:

[image: unhewn Kotel bottom block]

[image: unhewn lower-level Kotel block]

Archeologists learned some fascinating things about the architectural process of the building of the Temple from the fact that many or perhaps even most of the bottom blocks were not completely hewn, but I was a little shocked (still am), because in my mind the Temple was supposed to have been built perfectly. It seemed not okay to me to have cut corners (excuse the pun) in the building of the Temple, even if this was part of the outer wall and was ultimately covered in mounds of dirt (this latter reason was why the university lecturer who had organized the trip hadn't been bothered by this fact).

I am aware that when the Second Temple was first built, corners were cut (see [Ezra 3:12-13](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Ezra.3.12-13?lang=bi); [Chagai 2:3-9](https://www.sefaria.org.il/Haggai.2.3-9?lang=bi)). But it was my impression that it was simply smaller than intended, probably even not decorated as nicely as the first one. That didn't mean that they didn't do their best to make the small structure itself as perfect as possible. Kal v'chomer, I would think with Herod's Temple, a project that was much better-funded. Were things like this truly okay?

Comment: As a kind of precedent: in the mishkan, the berichim are called "plated with gold", but Rashi says what that actually means is that they went through a pipe in the kerashim so that they looked plated with gold when the mishkan was assembled.  Apparently in some cases what matters is what it looks like in its final state.  On the other hand, when the mishkan was assembled nobody ever saw the adanim in the corners (from the outside they were covered by yerios, from the inside by their neighbors), but they still had to be silver.

Comment: I don't think wasting time and effort on something nobody could see counts as "cutting corners".

Comment: @N.T. As I said, that's what the university lecturer that came with us (a religious man, BTW) said. But I myself have difficulty accepting this.

Comment: This isn't cutting corners in the Temple. This is cutting corners out somewhere nearby at a halachically insignificant minor facade. Your question only starts because you grew up thinking the kotel is sooo important.

Comment: @DoubleAA As I indicated in the question, I'm well aware of what the ketalim are in terms of holiness and (non) importance. However, is this not comparable to a cloth covering the vessels during travel in the midbar? Would you just throw an old rag on it? And a rag could even be a piece of silk that is frayed at the edges. This is a cube covering the Temple Mount, which is a holy place. This cube is frayed at the edges. That doesn't bother you?

Comment: The coverings on the vessels were seen. These stones are not. And frayed implies weakness, but there is no structural weakness here. If it bothers you, it bothers you. I don't know what to tell you.